# Getting feature details from Geonetwork

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, iso-19115

I am using the metadata catalogue Geonetwork which deals with the metadata.
As far as I can see this metadata contains details about createdate,changedate,origin,title etc but does not contain anything related to features of the geographical data. I just want to be sure about my understanding
Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to geoNetwork, but with the metadata schema you are using. I am not sure if there is any metadata schema that supports definition of features, but if there is, you just have to use it and fill the fields so geoNetwork can know about them.

More info about metadata schemas here: http://www.fgdc.gov/metadata/geospatial-metadata-standards